# Get multiple Threads by ThreadID in Google Apps Script's GmailApp Class

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have an array of strings where each value represents a Gmail Threadid. This looks something like this:

```
var threadArray = [threadId1, threadId2, threadId3, threadId4, threadId5];
```

I want to apply a Gmail Label to each of the elements in my array of threadids, but my current approach is not efficient and takes too long to execute. See below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++)
{
    thread = getThreadById(threadArray[i]) // this statement takes too long (several seconds) to execute!!
    thread.addLabel(exampleLabel);
}
```

What's the best approach for applying a Gmail Label to each Gmail Thread in an array of Gmail ThreadIds?

Gmail provides functions like `getInboxThreads()` which retrieve many threads at once to return GmailThread[] but its unclear to me how I can construct my own GmailThread[] purely based on the threadids, not my entire inbox.

Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a workaround?  I found a similar open issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a long time for such task is not really an issue, you can easily manage to get it working on (relatively) small bunches based on a timer trigger.

I have a similar script that runs every night and it works nicely... it works for 4 minutes then wait a bit and continues until all the threads have been treated.

You only need to store the index where to start from (in scriptProperties) and measure elapsed time during script execution.

Comment: thank you!  I will use ScriptProperties & a time-based trigger to govern the execution.  That will solve my problem.  From your experience can the "wait a bit" part be as short as any of the Time-Based Trigger increments?

Comment: I use a trigger that fires every 5 minutes and limit the execution time to about 4 minutes... so I have 1 minute to be sure I don't "overlap".

Comment: Hi Serge, what's a simple way to "measure elapsed time" during the context of my execution?  Should i instatiate a timer variable  var timer = currentTime at the beginning of my script and then periodically determine the concept of "elapsed time" based on some "later current time" - currentTime?

Comment: Exactly :-)  that's why I said "about 4 minutes" because it depends on the size of the "steps", in other word the duration of one loop iteration.